# Can I connect Play Store comments to JIRA?

Tags: google-play, jira, jira-plugin

Is is possible to connect play store comments to JIRA so that issues raised by users can be viewed on Dashboard directly? Same can be converted to issue from dashboard and assigned to developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Play Store plugin for JIRA as of now. If you wish you can create a custom plugin using Google Apps API.